# react,js calculator not concatenating numbers

Tags: reactjs, concatenation, calculator

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Calculator = () => {
  const [displayValue, setDisplayValue] = useState('0');
  const [operations, setOperations] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.getAttribute('data-value');
    if (value === 'C') {
      setDisplayValue('0');
      setOperations([]);
    } else if (value === 'CE') {
      setDisplayValue('0');
      setOperations(operations.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (value === '=') {
      const result = eval(operations.join(''));
      setDisplayValue(result);
      setOperations([]);
    } else if (!isNaN(value)) {
      // Handle number buttons
      setDisplayValue(displayValue === '0' ? value : displayValue + value);
    } else {
      // Handle operation buttons
      if (displayValue !== '') {
        setOperations([...operations, displayValue, value]);
        setDisplayValue('');
      }
    }
  };

  const renderButtons = () => {
    const buttons = [
      ['7', '8', '9', '+'],
      ['4', '5', '6', '-'],
      ['1', '2', '3', '/'],
      ['.', '0', 'C', '=']
    ];

    return buttons.map((row) => {
      return (
        <div className="button-row">
          {row.map((button) => {
            return (
              <button
                key={button}
                data-value={button}
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                {button}
              </button>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="calculator">
      <div className="display">{displayValue}</div>
      {renderButtons()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Calculator;
```

This is my code for a simple calculator using react.js

The problem is when I digit a number, for exemple "40", the display only shows 4, and than 0, never 4 and 0 together, although the final result after= is correct.

40+50=90.

But when I digit it only shows 4, than 0, than 5, than 0. One at the time.

How to fix it?

I tried several ways to fix it without good results.

Answer (score 0):

You were not adding the last number that was displaying before clicking the `=` sign. I've added some conditions to add the last display value

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Calculator = () => {
  const [displayValue, setDisplayValue] = useState("0");
  const [operations, setOperations] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = e.target.getAttribute("data-value");
    if (value === "C") {
      setDisplayValue("0");
      setOperations([]);
    } else if (value === "=") {
      console.log(operations);
      if (operations.length === 0) {
        setDisplayValue("0");
      } else {
        
        const result = eval(operations.join("") + displayValue);
        setDisplayValue(result);
        setOperations([]);
      }
    } else if (!isNaN(value)) {
      // Handle number buttons
      console.log("num", value);
      setDisplayValue(displayValue === "0" ? value : displayValue + value);
    } else {
      // Handle operation buttons
      if (displayValue !== "") {
        setOperations([...operations, displayValue, value]);

        setDisplayValue("");
      }
    }
  };
  console.log("num", displayValue);
  console.log("op array", operations);

  const renderButtons = () => {
    const buttons = [
      ["7", "8", "9", "+"],
      ["4", "5", "6", "-"],
      ["1", "2", "3", "/"],
      [".", "0", "C", "="]
    ];

    return buttons.map((row) => {
      return (
        <div className="button-row">
          {row.map((button, index) => {
            return (
              <button key={index} data-value={button} onClick={handleClick}>
                {button}
              </button>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="calculator">
      <div className="display">{displayValue}</div>
      {renderButtons()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Calculator;
```

also I've removed the `CE` operation as it was serving no purpose

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but somehow the code still doesn't work.

The problem persists.

Comment: @Hluger could you run this in codesandbox...I found no issues while running it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-ives-7hmnxt?file=/src/Calculator.css

Strange. In codeSandBox it works, but in vs code not.

Also, in codeSandBox the CSS is broken, but in vs code it works just fine

Comment: @Hluger exactly...In sandbox I found no problem...maybe there are some internal issues in vscode...better to recheck